# Using column command on tput result over bash

Tags: bash, tput

I have a variable "x" , which contains two columns and two row. I wanted to print "hi" in RED color, so I took help of `tput` ,which printed the result in red. But I also needed to print the columns in proper alignment for that I used `column -t` but it is distorting the output. This was due to the fact that some control chars are added by tput.

```
x="hello $(tput setaf 1)hi $(tput sgr0) whatsup
hey howdy cya"


echo "$x"
hello hi  whatsup
hey howdy cya

echo "$x"|column -t
hello  hi              whatsup
hey    howdy  cya
```

I was expecting:

```
hello  hi     whatsup
hey    howdy  cya
```

Tried to debug ,found that tput is adding some control chars to make "hi" print in red.

```
echo "$x"|cat -A
hello ^[[31mhi ^[(B^[[m whatsup$
hey howdy cya$
```

**Question:**

How to "`column -t`" on colored output from tput?

EDIT: Result(ALL IN RED) from @Diego Torres Milano

```
hello  31mhi  Bm  whatsup
hey    howdy   cya
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a kind of simplified *markup*, in this case `^A` for your red (to enter it using `vim` type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>)

```
y="hello ^Ahi whatsup
hey howdy ya"

echo "$y"|column -t|sed -E "s@^A([[:alnum:]]+)@$(tput setaf 1)\1$(tput sgr0)@g"
```

and the output is as expected (hi is in red):

```
hello  hi     whatsup
hey    howdy  ya
```

## EDIT

if your `column` counts the control chars, then use any char that's not appearing in your values and then replace them, like

```
y="|hello !hi |whatsup
|hey |howdy |ya"

echo "$y"|column -t|sed -E "s@\\|@@g; s@!([[:alnum:]]+)@$(tput setaf 1)\1$(tput sgr0)@g;"
```

which produces

[image: column color]

Comment: Hello,  added the output in the answer. Thanks. Its not same as yours.